# Weekly Menu Rotation

Tags: php, css

So basically i have a Project where i have to make our Menu Order Website better, for that i want to Include a Weekly rotating menu where the Users can order, i have the whole website done including the Admin panels yet i cant figure out how to create a rotating website, for now i have all Menus included in the Main Website i tried it with Wordpress code, which i then realised isnt supported in basic php... the only code i find is from 2014 and i dont have a clue where to include it in my code as im a Newbie :) What would be cool is like a small dropdown button where you can show the next weeks menu too

Main Site section to order menus

```
<!-- fOOD sEARCH Section Starts Here -->
<section class="food-search text-center">
    <div class="container">
        
        <form action="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>food-search.php" method="POST">
            <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for Food.." required>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>

    </div>
</section>
<!-- fOOD sEARCH Section Ends Here -->



<!-- fOOD MEnu Section Starts Here -->
<section class="food-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">Mama Bringts Menüs</h2>

        <?php
            //Zeigt Menüs an die auf Active gesetzt sind
            $sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl_food WHERE active='Yes'";

            //Query ausführen
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            //Rows zählen
            $count= mysqli_num_rows($res);

            //Schauen ob die Menüs verfügbar (Active) sind
            if($count>0)
            {
                //Verfügbar
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                {
                    //Werte auslesen
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $price = $row['price'];
                    $image_name =$row['image_name'];
                    ?>

                    <div class="food-menu-box">
                                    <div class="food-menu-img">
                                        <?php
                                            //Bild verfügbar oder nicht
                                            if($image_name=="")
                                            {
                                                //Bild nicht verfügbar
                                                echo "<div class='error'>Das Bild ist nicht verfügbar</div>";
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //Bild verfügbar
                                                ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>images/food/<?php echo $image_name; ?>" alt="Chicke Hawain Pizza" class="img-responsive img-curve">
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="food-menu-desc">
                                        <h4><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                                        <p class="food-price"><?php echo $price; ?></p>
                                        <p class="food-detail">
                                            <?php echo $description; ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <br>

                                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>order.php?food_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Jetzt Bestellen</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                    <?php
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //Nicht verfügbar
                echo "<div class='error'>Das Menü wurde nicht gefunden!</div>";
            }
        ?>

        

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        

    </div>

</section>
<!-- fOOD Menu Section Ends Here -->

<?php include('partials-front/footer.php')?>
```

Admin Site to Manage the Menus

```
    <!-- Main Content Section -->
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Administrator Verwaltung</h1>
            <br /><br /><br />

            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['add']))
                {
                    echo $_SESSION['add']; //Zeigt Session Nachricht an
                    unset($_SESSION['add']); //Entfernt Session Nachricht
                }

                if(isset($_SESSION['delete']))
                {
                    Echo $_SESSION['delete'];
                    unset($_SESSION['delete']);
                }

                if(isset($_SESSION['update']))
                {
                    echo $_SESSION['update'];
                    unset($_SESSION['update']);
                }

                if(isset($_SESSION['user-not-found']))
                {
                    echo $_SESSION['user-not-found'];
                    unset($_SESSION['user-not-found']);
                }

                if(isset($_SESSION['pwd-not-match']))
                {
                    echo $_SESSION['pwd-not-match'];
                    unset($_SESSION['pwd-not-match']);
                }

                if(isset($_SESSION['change-pwd']))
                {
                    echo $_SESSION['change-pwd'];
                    unset($_SESSION['change-pwd']);
                }
            ?>
            <br><br><br>

            <!-- Button to add Admin -->
            <a href="add-admin.php" class="btn-primary">Add Admin</a>
        

            <br/><br/><br/>

            <table class="tbl-full">
                <tr>
                <th>S.N.</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    //Fügt alle Admins zum Table hinzu
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin";
                    //Führt die Query aus
                    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    //Schaut nach ob die Query ausgeführt wurde oder nicht
                    if($res==TRUE)
                    {
                        // Zählt die Zeilen in der Datenbank um zu schauen ob wir Daten in der Bank haben oder nicht
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res); // Holt sich alle Zeilen der Datenbank

                        $sn=1; //Created die Variablen und Weisst die den Admins zu 

                        //Checkt die Anzahl von Zeilen
                        if($count>0)
                        {
                            //Haben Daten in Datenbank         
                            while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))       
                            {
                                //Benutzen While loop um die Daten in der Datenbank zu bekommen
                                //Der Loop lauft so lang wir Daten haben

                                //Individuelle Daten ziehen
                                $id=$rows['id'];
                                $full_name=$rows['full_name'];
                                $username=$rows['username'];

                                //Values im Table anzeigen
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $sn++; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $full_name; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/update-password.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn-primary">Change Password</a>    
                                    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/update-admin.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn-secondary" >Update Admin</a> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/delete-admin.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn-danger" >Delete Admin</a> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                
                                
                            }              
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Wir haben keine Daten in der Datenbank

                        }
                    }
                ?>

                
            </table>
            <!-- Button Ende -->


        </div>
```

Comment: Add a `week` column in your database? Then in PHP get the current week number ( `date('W')` ) and use it in your query.

Comment: i tried that.. yet i cant seem to figure out how to just add the week instead of the whole date googling didnt rly get me further :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been fixed, used this code for Sorting and switching through Menus

```
<html>  
    <head>  
    <title></title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
            <select name='kwlist'> 
            <option value="">--- KW wählen ---</option>  


            <?php

            $sql = "SELECT KW, Year from tbl_food ORDER BY `tbl_food`.`Year`, `tbl_food`.`KW` ASC LIMIT 3;";

                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                  
                $count= mysqli_num_rows($res);
 
                if($count>0)
                {
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))  
            {
                    $KW = $row['KW'];
                    $year = $row['Year'];



                    echo '<option value="'.$KW.'/'.$year.'">'.$KW.' / '.$year.'</option>';
            }
        
        } 
                             
            ?>  
</select>  
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Auswählen" />  
        </form>  
    </body>  
</html>  

<?php
                //Sortiert Menüs nach KW max 1 Woche vor und 1 Woche rückblickend

                if(isset($_POST['kwlist']) && $_POST['kwlist'] != "")
                {
                    $kwyear = explode("/", $_POST['kwlist']);
                    //echo $kwyear[0]; // KW
                    //echo $kwyear[1]; // Jahr
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_food WHERE `KW` =$kwyear[0] AND `Year` =$kwyear[1]";
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $actual_kw = date('W');
                    $actual_year = date('Y');
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_food WHERE `KW` = $actual_kw AND `Year` = $actual_year";
                }
```